# Validation on the length of the string in WTform does not work

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

Validation on the length of the string in Wtform does not work, I tried to use "if form.validate_on_submit ():" in the post method, but it gives the value:False regardless of the parameters in the input field.

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from forms import Article
from models import db, Library


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "hard_string_security"


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    form = Article()
    date_db = Library.select()
    #             if form.validate_on_submit():   
    if request.method == "POST":
        db.connect()
        new_article = Library(titleArticle=form.title, contentArticle=form.content)
        new_article.save()
        db.close()
        print(form.validate_on_submit())
        return redirect(url_for(".index"))


    return render_template("index.html", date_db=date_db, form=form)
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length


class Article(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField("Input title arcicle", validators=[Length(min=1, max=5),DataRequired()])
    content = TextAreaField("Input content arcicle", validators=[DataRequired()])

    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Create Article</h2>
    <form method="post" action="/">
        {{ form.title.label }}{{ form.title }}<br>
        {{ form.content.label }}{{ form.content }}<br>
        {{ form.submit }}<br><br>
    </form>
    
    </body>

</html>
```